# Java - need to invoke one of three methods based on user input

Tags: java, methods, user-input

I have an assignment to write medical billing program in Java (via eclipse). We are required to write three billing methods, one of which the user will select. I've written the methods, but have two problems how do I invoke the method chosen by the user, also, I have a red squiggly line in one of the methods and don't know why. Can anyone suggest the best way to invoke the corresponding billing method based on user input?

Also, can you tell me why Billing method 2 aka "calcBillMed" has a red squiggly line? under billAmount? Do I have to declare billAmount under all three methods?

import java.util.Scanner;
public class PatientBillingV2 {

//import java.text.NumberFormat;
//import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

```
//Project requirements
//Loop until the user enters -1 for the patient last name
//Request patient last name, first name, claim amount and billing method, 1,2,3

public static void main(String[] args) {  
    double billAmount;
    String method;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    displayTitle();
    adjustName(null);

     System.out.print("\n\n Enter claim amount: ");
     billAmount = scan.nextDouble();

      System.out.println("Choose billing type of: deductible, Medicare or co-pay: ");
      method =scan.nextLine();
  >>>>>>>>>>>>>I want the code to go to the correct method based on user input starting here<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<   
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------
// Displays program title
//-------------------------------------------------------------
 public static void displayTitle() 
 {        
      System.out.println("Patient Billing");
 }

 //------------------------------------------------------------
 //Formats patients last name and first name, converting the first character of each to upper case
 //------------------------------------------------------------
 public static void adjustName(String in) 
 {    
      String lastname, firstname, method;

      Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

      System.out.println("Enter patients last name: ");
      lastname = scan.nextLine();
      System.out.println(lastname.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + lastname.substring(1));

      System.out.println("Enter paitents fist name: ");
      firstname = scan.nextLine();
      System.out.println(firstname.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + firstname.substring(1));
 }

 //------------------------------------------------------------
 //Billing method 1, coverage percent = 80 with a $50 deductible, unless bill is less than $50
 //-----------------------------------------------------------

public double calcBillDeduct (double billAmount, double method1a, double method1b) 
{
     final double coveredPercent = .80;
     double deductible = 50.00;
     double total;

     //Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


        if (billAmount > deductible)
        {   
            total = (billAmount + deductible) * coveredPercent;
            System.out.println("\t\t  Billing method deductible, amount due = " + method1a);
        }
        else
        {
             total = (billAmount * coveredPercent) - deductible;
            System.out.println("\t\t  Billing method deductible, claim amount is less than the deductible  = " + method1b);
        }       

        return total;
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------       
// Billing method2 - Medicare - patient is billed 35% of claim amount
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
public double calcBillMed (double medicare)
{
        final double medicadePercent = .35;

        medicare = billAmount * medicadePercent;
        System.out.println("\t\t  Billing method Medicare, amount due = " + medicare);
}       
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Billing method3 is co-pay amount of $15 regardless of claim amount
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
public double calcCoPay (double coPay)      
{
    final double copay = 35;

}
```

}

Comment: make all your methods public static in order to invoke them within your main method. This is because your main is declared publicly static and therefore static method can only call other static methods. hence the red lines for your last three functions.

Comment: Hi Raz-Muh_Taz, thanks for the tip that makes sense. Question, though, I made them all public static double, and tried public static void, either way I get the red squiggly lines. What am I doing wrong? Should I use something other than void or double?

Answer (score 0):

You need to take some input from the user. You're halfway there:

```
System.out.println("Choose billing type of: deductible, Medicare or co-pay: ");
method = scan.nextLine();
```

Now `method` should contain the name of the method that the user want's to invoke. There's a few ways you could act on this information, here's one way using a `switch` statement.

```
boolean valid = isValidMethod(method); // make a method that ensures that the user entered something sane. Check if it's null, check if it corresponds to a valid method name, etc.

if(!valid) {
    // user entered an invalid method, uh oh! ask them for valid input
    // I leave this to you
}

// it's valid, switch on the method name and call the appropriate method
switch(method) {
    case "calcBillDeduct":
        calcBillDeduct(billAmount, method1a, method1b);
        break;

    case "calcBillMed":
         calcBillMed(billAmount);
         break;

    // etc

    default:
         // good to include a default, but it's an invalid method in this case
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid method: " + method);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip Matt, I like the idea of a switch statement. Now the only problem I"m having is I have a red squiggly line under billAMount under all three methods.

Comment: If you hover over the red squiggly line your IDE will probably tell you what's wrong. Your `main` method is static. If you want to call other methods in the same class you need to make them static as well. The reason for this is that a static method can be called without instantiated the class, so you can't assume that the class is instantiated when you call another method - therefore they must be static as well.

Answer (score 0):

For the billAmount issue, yes you must declare billAmount as a variable or make it a class field to be able to reference and modify it.

Also you need to make methods static if you want to access them without an instantiated object.

This is called Variable scope. a variable created in one method is only accessible to that single function. a class field variable is accessible to all non-static methods in that class.

As for prompting the user for input and selecting a method based on that input the best way to do this is to run either an if/else block or a switch statement and prompt them for an integer value

```
System.out.println("Choose billing type:\n1. Deductible\n2. Medicare\n3. co-pay");
int selection = scan.nextInt();
boolean validSelection = false;
while(!validSelection) {
    switch (selection) {
        case 1:
            calcBillDeduct(billAmount, method1a, method1b);
            validSelection = true;
            break;
        case 2:
            calcBillMed(billAmount);
            validSelection = true;
            break;
        case 3:
            calcCoPay(coPay);
            validSelection = true;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First change the method signatures to be public static, keep the return value double.

```
public static double calcBillDeduct (double billAmount, double method1a, double method1b) 
{
   ....
}

public static double calcBillMed (double medicare)
{
   ....
}

public static double calcCoPay (double coPay)      
{
   ....
}
```

Next you need to declare the variable double billAmount; outside your main method if you are intending to use it within the functions without passing it to them via parameter.

```
public static double billAmount;
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   ....
}
```

This will put the variable in scope of the other methods and it must be static since you are calling everything within main which is static.

Lastly here is a simple do/while that asks for choices - deduct, medicare, or co-pay. All you have to do is fill in the if's with your method calls.

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input;
    do {
        System.out.println("Choose from the following options:\ndeduct\nmedicare\nco-pay\nexit");
        input = scan.nextLine();
        if(input.equals("deduct"))
        {

        }
        else if(input.equals("medicare"))
        {

        }
        else if(input.equals("co-pay"))
        {

        }
        else if(!input.equals("exit")) {
            System.out.println("Error with input : " + input);
        }

    } while (!input.equals("exit"));
```